Copying the previous block of code
// some
// code 1
    
// some
// code 2
    
// cursor here

I wish to quickly copy and paste the immediate previous block of code (2). By a block, I mean all code that is between two empty lines (let us assume that the code blocks don't have empty lines in within themselves).
This action mapped to a couple of keys will be really useful. I'm fairly new to Vim, and I tried doing this myself with nnoremap and some VimScript, but didn't get far.

What did you try?

Do you still have something open in your question? How can we help you further? Otherwise maybe could you accept one of the answers using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

@romainl I tried finding all the empty lines in the file and picking the last one. However, this would fail if there is code after cursor as well. I couldnt find a way to go to the empty line immediately before the cursor. I could technically list all the empty lines and the cursor line and find the closet line number but that would mean running through the whole file which is very inefficient

That should be part of your question.

@romainl I understand. Ill make sure to include work next time onwards.

I would do something like:
nnoremap <C-s> {y}<C-o><C-o>P


{ move before the start of the previous paragraph
y} yank (copy) the paragraph
<C-o><C-o> comeback to the cursor position
P paste the lines before


I think there is some issue with step 2. It highlights the whole file.

Thanks for the feedback. I have adapted the solution :-)

print("sus")
i = 9
for j in range(i):
print(j)
print("goo")
when I do ctrl-s it now pastes only print("sus")

oops the formatting is bad. Here is the pastebin

I think changing 2. step to simply { works

nnoremap <C-s> {jy}}p this also works, I believe. Have I missed something here?

There are small problems. The {j will not work for the first paragraph. The }} will not bring you back your previous position all the time. But it is already very good.

I agree. There is some clean-up to do, but this does the job mostly. Thanks a lot for the help! Please do update us if you come up with a more sophisticated version! I will do too :)

Thanks for the feedback. Welcome to Vim :-)

Oh I did not notice the edit. The current one works really well. Cheers!
